# How to sort external fields using Paginator in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I'm developing an application using cakephp 3.0.
I'm wondering if the paginator allows to sort fields coming from other tables which are included in the 'contain' clause.
For example I have this statement:

```
    $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Actors']
    ];
```

The table 'Actors' contains the field 'description'. Is it possible to sort by the description field of the table Actors?

I tried to specify the field using the dot notation:

```
$this->Paginator->sort('Actors.description', __('Description'))
```

as well as to include the model within the option array:

```
$this->Paginator->sort('description', __('Description'), ['model' => 'Actors'])
```

In both cases it doesn't seem to work. These two approaches come from cakephp 2.0 where everything works fine ([cakephp Paginator -> sort - model option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273380/cakephp-paginator-sort-model-option)). Apparently in the new documentation there aren't any updates.

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948164/pagination-sort-in-cakephp-3-x?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: thank you. This helped me a lot. Below you may read how I solved my issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As José Lorenzo says here [Pagination Sort in Cakephp 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948164/pagination-sort-in-cakephp-3-x?answertab=votes#tab-top), Paginator blocks each field which is not available in the primary table.
Thus if you need to order by a foreign field it is necessary to specify the full qualified name used by cakephp in the joining table.

In my example I need to specify the following:

```
$this->paginate = [
    'contain' => ['Actors'],
    'sortWhitelist'=>['Actors.description']
];
```

and use this expression in the view:

```
<?= $this->Paginator->sort('Actors.description', __('Description')) ?>
```

In this way everything works like a charm. If you are not able to identify the right field you may enable the query debug and see which field is used in the query.