# How to order the primary model by associated data?

Tags: cakephp, sql-order-by, cakephp-3.0

## Situation

using Cake 3.2.6

## What I want

To display a list of `PaymentsByMembers` by the members' `role_id` in ascending order followed by their `name`

In other words I want to order the primary models by the associated data fields.

## What I tried

```
   $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => [
            'Issuers', 
            'Recipients', 'PaymentTypes'
        ],
        'conditions' => $conditions, 
        'order' => ['Recipients.role_id' => 'ASC', 'Recipients.name' => 'ASC']
    ];
```

## what's the relations?

A `Payments by Member` belongsTo a `Recipient`

## What did you find?

I can only find a section in the cookbook about [filtering by associated data](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#filtering-by-associated-data).

There is no equivalent about ordering by associated data.

I will be happy to write that in.

Comment: please explain the relationships between your models

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort external fields using Paginator in CakePHP 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31916341/how-to-sort-external-fields-using-paginator-in-cakephp-3)